# How to add 2 new() constraint for to type parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, syntax, generic-constraints

I want something like this:

```
public static TTo JumpTo<TFrom, TTo>(this TFrom from_page) 
       where TTo : new() TFrom : new()
{
    ...
}
```

And I want to enforce that TFrom and TTo are both derived from a base type.

And I want to make this method as **an extension method** of TFrom type.

Is it possible ? And what's the correct syntax?

Comment: @AD.Net: And your point with that demand? Edit: and that wont compile.

Comment: Btw the, the `new` constraint on the input parameter does not really make sense, unless you copying stuff internally.

Comment: @AD.Net: That sounds more like VB.NET except in VB.NET it would be `Of TTo As SomeType, TFrom As SomeOtherType` so actually not at all

Comment: you guys are right, got my syntax wrong!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the keyword `where` before each type.

```
public static TTo JumpTo<TFrom, TTo>(this TFrom from_page) 
    where TTo : SomeBaseType, new() 
    where TFrom : SomeOtherBaseType, new()
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and I want to make JumpTo as an **extension method** of TFrom. Is it possible?

Comment: @smwikipedia: Your edit just did that! You add to a static class.

Comment: @smwikipedia Yes you can make it an extensions method.

Comment: Currently, I put the method into a static class. But the method does not show for the TFrom type. I am still trying on it.

Comment: @smwikipedia please post a complete example, including the containing static class.

Comment: I got it, I removed the new() constraint for TFrom and it shows up now. It turns out my TFrom type doesn't have a parameterless constructor.